# Update parent table cell value from child table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a table (parent) and one another table inside that table(child).

I want to update the cell value of parent table from child table.

```html
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-4 nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Restaurant Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Delivery Date")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Status")
                </th>
                <th class="none">
                    @Html.DisplayName("Preferred Delivery Date")
                </th>
                <th class="none">
                    <b> @Html.DisplayName("Item List") </b>
                </th>
                <th class="none"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.DELIVERED_DATE)
                    @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELIVERED_DATE.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.STATUS == 1)
                    {
                        <span class="badge badge-secondary">Draft</span>
                    }
                    @if (item.STATUS == 2)
                    {
                        <span class="badge badge-warning">Pending confirmation</span>
                    }
                    @if (item.STATUS == 3)
                    {
                        <span class="badge badge-primary">Confirmed</span>
                    }
                    @if (item.STATUS == 4)
                    {
                        <span class="badge badge-suceess">Delivered</span>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    :  @String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.PREFERRED_DELIVERY_DATE)
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayName("Item Name")
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayName("Quantity")
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayName("Price")
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach (var test in item.OrderSupplierItems)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test.IngredientName)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test.QUANTITY)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => test.PRICE)$</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">Sum</td>
                                    <td>@item.OrderSupplierItems.Sum(b => b.PRICE)$</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <a class='Confirm btn btn-success' href='javascript:;@item.ID_ORDER_SUPPLIER'>CONFIRM</a>
                    <a class='btn btn-primary'>MAKE CHANGES</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to change the status on ajax success request.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#example TBODY .Confirm", function () {
        if (confirm("Do you want to confirm this order?")) {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var orderSupplierId = $(this).attr('href').substr(12); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceUrl"]/api/OrderSupplier/" + orderSupplierId +"?status=3",
                contentType: 'application/json',  // <---add this
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function (response) {
//here i want to do this
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

I need to update the status field of parent table based on confirm changes button.
I need to replace the current text of status field of current table.

Comment: That confirm status is coming from backend ? what exactly `response` has ?

Comment: You dont need to worry about response, i only want to update the row text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest('tr').find("td:eq(3)")` this will refer to 4th column `td` in your table i.e : status column and use `.html` or `.text` to make changes there .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("body").on("click", ".Confirm", function() {
  if (confirm("Do you want to confirm this order?")) {
    var row = $(this); //declare this outside..ajax call
    var orderSupplierId = $(this).attr('href').substr(12);
    //ajaxcodes..
    //success: function(response) {
    //here i want to do this
    row.closest('tr').find("td:eq(3)").html('<span class="badge badge-primary">Confirmed</span>')
    //},
    //other codes
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped mt-4 nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
      <th></th>
      <th>
        Restaurant Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Delivery Date
      </th>
      <th>
        Status
      </th>
      <th class="none">
        Preferred Delivery Date
      </th>
      <th class="none">
        <b>Item List </b>
      </th>
      <th class="none"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        Somehtings..
      </td>
      <td>
        02/02/202
      </td>
      <td>

        <span class="badge badge-warning">Pending confirmation</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        02/3/2020
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
              <th>
                Item Name
              </th>
              <th>
                Quantity
              </th>
              <th>
                Price
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>

              <tr>
                <td>somehting</td>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>12$</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Sum</td>
                <td>123$</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class='Confirm btn btn-success' href='javascript:;@item.ID_ORDER_SUPPLIER'>CONFIRM</a>
        <a class='btn btn-primary'>MAKE CHANGES</a>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          Somehtings..
        </td>
        <td>
          02/02/202
        </td>
        <td>

          <span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          02/3/2020
        </td>
        <td>

          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-primary text-light">
                <th>
                  Item Name
                </th>
                <th>
                  Quantity
                </th>
                <th>
                  Price
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>somehting</td>
                  <td>abc</td>
                  <td>12$</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Sum</td>
                  <td>123$</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a class='Confirm btn btn-success' href='javascript:;@item.ID_ORDER_SUPPLIER'>CONFIRM</a>
          <a class='btn btn-primary'>MAKE CHANGES</a>
        </td>
        </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for me, its updating the 12$ value.

Comment: I m using the datatable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: 'column'
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [{
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets: 0
            }],
            order: [1, 'asc']
        });

Comment: row.closest('tr').closest('table').find("td:eq(3)") , this works , thanks for your help, i am accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can search back from the element you're in, which is the button, with .closest(). Then find the status field from there. Best would be to give the status a class or id. So:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('.status')
```

Comment: What is the problem? That I yse $ to show that it is a jquery object?

Comment: its closest, i tried but it is not working, anyway thanks

Comment: I fixed the typo. Sorry. But you have to show more code of what you are actually doing.

Comment: And I did remove the $, to avoid discussion... I find it a good habit, though.

Comment: @AyushShukla You say it's not working, but then show me what you wrote. Closest is absolutely the way to travers the parents, so...

Comment: @AyushShukla I looked at your html, but your confirm-button is actually not in the child table. I will change my answer. Just a minute.